# LINQ: delete from a list elements contained in another list

Tags: .net, linq

I have a list (`List<T>`) of objects `aList` and another list `bList`.

How to use Linq to delete all objects from `aList` contained in `bList`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way would be to do this:

```
foreach(var item in bList) aList.Remove(item);
```

`Remove` doesn't do anything if the item isn't already in the list.

If by "use LINQ" you mean use LINQ to determine if an item in `aList` is in `bList`, that's not necessary.

A LINQ solution would be more efficient ONLY if both of these conditions are true:

1. `aList` is very small compared to `bList`
2. All of the items in `aList` that are also in `bList` are at the very beginning of `bList`

Comment: I could use LINQ however (sorry for VB.NET): `bList.ForEach(Sub(item) aList.Remove(item))`?

Comment: @serhio: That isn't LINQ, it's just using an anonymous delegate and the (controversial) `ForEach` function. There's no benefit to using that.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a)

```
aList.RemoveAll(x => bList.Contains(x))
```

FWIW, this will also remove all objects in `aList` contained in `bList`, not only the first instance of each `bList` object in `aList`, if this is important.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Correct me if I'm wrong, but the worst case in my answer is `bList` does not contain `x` which will iterate once through the entire `bList`, and the worst case in your answer is `aList` does not contain `item` which will iterate once through the entire `aList` - effectively the same. In fact MSDN specifcally states both `Remove` and `RemoveAll` perform a linear search.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it would be the same worst-case scenario. But yours uses delegate invocation, which is slower ;) FWIW, I did +1 given that the OP did ask for LINQ.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Yes, I do agree the delegate would be slower. I'm not sure if it is important to the OP but this *will* remove all matches from the list if there is duplication. If that is not necessary though I suggest to go with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) extension method:

```
var result = aList.Except(bList);
```

Note that you can also pass an [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151) as a second argument if you need to customize the equality checking.

Comment: Keep in mind this creates a projection and does not actually remove the items from the original list. Technically the OP asked to remove the items from `aList`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the LINQ "Except" extension:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/except

> Except subtracts elements from a collection. This extension method is found in the System.Linq namespace in the .NET Framework. It essentially subtracts all the elements in one collection from another.

Comment: Keep in mind this creates a projection and does not actually remove the items from the original list. Technically the OP asked to remove the items from `aList`.

Comment: Yes. I have voted for the more relevant and correct answer. Thank you.